# how to find the number of ways of choosing k objects of 3 types

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, combinatorics

You are given an integer `k` and 3 types of objects - A, B and C each type has a large supply of objects. In how many ways can u arrange `k` objects so that you can choose any type of object any number of times with one restriction that B always comes between A and C or C and A.

for example if, k is 3, then the answer is : 10
explanation : {AAA, AAC, ABC, ACA, ACC, CAA, CAC, CBA, CCA, CCC}

I tried to solve it using dynamic programming, I don't know if that's the correct approach, though.

I tried something like this : `f(n) = 2*f(n-1) + f(n-2)`, where you take an array of size `k` and `f(1) = 2 {A, C}`and `f(2) = 4 {AA, AC, CA, CC}`,

so if(n-1)th alphabet is A or C, then nth alphabet can A or C, but if it's B, then nth alphabet can only be the complementary aplphabet i.e, if (n-2)th letter is A, then nth letter is C or vice versa. But I feel like I'm missing some cases.

Is there a better way, can someone help me with this?

Comment: If this a question from any competitive programming website then please add its link in question, I would like to test my logic there first before answering here.

Comment: don't remember the site.

Comment: Is (**ABBC**) a valid selection ? B is between A and C

Comment: @RohitRawat : No, every B should always come between A and C or C and A

Comment: This question from [mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/). You should asked there.

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay : this's also a programming question, where i had a doubt about the correct approach.

Comment: One closed form is `f(n) = sqrt(2)((1+sqrt(2))^n-(1-sqrt(2))^n)/2`, which is technically O(1), but I haven't found a way to get rid of the radical.

Answer (score 0):

**[Edited]**

Recursion:

```
F(1) = 2
F(2) = 4
F(N) = 2 * F(N - 1) + F(N-2)
```

explanation: 
any valid combination ends with A or C.
To make n-combination, we can add both A and C to any (n-1)-combination - two variants.
And we have one more variant, adding to (n-2) combinations: BA for xxxxC and BC for xxxxA

Comment: This is not correct. The recursion in the original post is correct. Consider ABCC. You cannot generate it from a valid two-character sequence, so you are not counting it.

Comment: This recurrence fails to count, amongst others, ABCA.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. F(4) = 24: sixteen possible combinations without B, four combinations containing ABC and four combinations containing CBA.

Comment: Yep, corrected to take into account such combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Let L be the language of such strings, and La and Lc be the subsets of the language where the strings end with A or C respectively.

Then we can write this unambiguous grammar:

```
L = La | Lc
La = "A" | L + "A" | Lc + "BA"
Lc = "C" | L + "C" | La + "BC"
```

Let L(n), La(n), Lc(n) be the number of strings of length n in each of the three languages. By symmetry, La(n) = Lc(n) = L(n)/2.

Then, from the second equation and using the fact that the grammar is unambiguous, for n > 1, La(n) = L(n-1) + Lc(n-2), and substituting we get: L(n) = 2L(n-1) + L(n-2). We have L(0)=0 and L(1)=2.

To compute L, we can write iterative code (which you might call dynamic programming):

```
def L(n):
    a, b = 0, 2
    for _ in xrange(n):
        a, b = b, a + 2 * b
    return a
```

Or, like we do for the Fibonacci series, we can solve it using matrix exponentiation, which can be done in O(log n) arithmetic operations.

```
L(n) = the first component of [0 1]^n (0)
                              [1 2]   (2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a generalised solution. Say you have `n` number of objects and you have to choose `k` objects out of them. You can choose `x1,x2,x3..` objects from each type.
And their sum

```
x1+x2+x3...+xn=k 0<=xi
```

Hence, provided you can select each object or not (`0<=xi`), the answer will be `(k+n-1)C(n-1)`

This is a simple solution of an integral equation